# TortoiseHg: How to split changes in commit dialog

Tags: split, mercurial, commit, tortoisehg

**Background:**
In the commit dialog of TortoiseHg all changes within a file are shown separate and can be selected/commited independendly.
This works fine as long as different changes are not too near together within a file. But sometimes two different changes (which I want to commit separately) are detected as one single change.

**Question:**
How can I split a change into two separate changes in order to commit one change after the other?